# Octopress blog deploys on localhost, has no log errors, throws "no such app" message on Heroku

Tags: heroku, octopress

I have an Octopress blog (amyhua.me, github.com/amyhua/amyhua-me) that I've generated with several posts and have deployed to Heroku. I've configured my DNS correctly (product check on DNS configuration passes), and the blog works on my local host. I did a `git push heroku master` which was successful, and the heroku logs show no apparent errors. But when I try to visit my heroku app at amyhua-me.herokuapp.com, it shows a message:

> "Heroku | No such app
>   There is no app configured at that hostname.
>   Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL."

I even started over with a new heroku app, deleting my former amyhua-me heroku app, and creating a new one I named amyhua-me (since my DNS servers point to amyhua-me.herokuapp.com), and it still throws a "No such app" message when I visit the herokuapp url.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone who cares, I solved my own problem.
It was the difference between pointing to `www.mydomain.herokuapp.com` versus `mydomain.herokuapp.com` from my DNS server.

Pointing to `mydomain.herokuapp.com` goes to my heroku app, `mydomain`.

Pointing to `www.mydomain.herokuapp.com` goes to a "Heroku | No such app" page.

Lesson learned: don't use the "www" in your DNS configuration!

Or.... just avoid the hassle and use the [Zerigo DNS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/zerigo_dns) heroku plug-in.